# Distribute evenly in 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, distribute, evenly

So i'm trying to distribute 2D items evenly accros the screen.
Right now I have it working in a way where i select all items and it calculates the size of the canvas, than calculates all widths of objects together to see how much whitespace it has. Than i distribute them evenly with the right amount of whitespace between the objects. Works great. However, as soon as I get more than 4 items or i don't have enough whitespace (objects are to big for example) I want to create a second row and move the first row up.

Below is my code.

```
public static void DistEvenly(PageObjectBase pageObject)
    {
        //List for objects
        List<PageObjectBase> objectList = new List<PageObjectBase>();
        float combinedWidth = 0;
        PageObjectGroup group = (PageObjectGroup) pageObject;

        //Start position is the left side of workField
        float leftStartPosition = -Config.DefaultWorkfieldSize.x / 2;
        int objectCount =0;

        //For every object add it to list and calculate width and add it to combinedWidth
        foreach (PageObjectBase objectBase in group.Children)
        {
            objectList.Add(objectBase);
            float imageWidth = objectBase.BoxCollider.size.x * objectBase.transform.localScale.x;
            combinedWidth = combinedWidth + imageWidth;
        }

        //whiteSpace is the remaining white space on the screen
        float whiteSpace = Config.DefaultWorkfieldSize.x - combinedWidth;

        //For each object place it at left start position and calculate the space between each image.
        foreach (PageObjectBase objectBase in group.Children)
        {
            if (whiteSpace > 20 && objectList.Count <= 4)
            {
                objectCount = objectList.Count + 1;
                objectBase.Move(leftStartPosition + whiteSpace / objectCount + objectBase.GetBoundsSize().x / 2, 0);
                Debug.Log("I should now distribute them evenly!");
                leftStartPosition = GetRightEdge(objectBase);
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

So as you can see it gets the amount of images in the list, calculates remaining whitespace and if there are a max of 4 items or less, and more than 20pixels of whitespace than i can distribute them. If this is false however (so more than 4 images or less than 20pixels of whitespace) i want to create a second row and move the first row up (right now it's on the 0 point of Y axis).

I tried a lot but I just cant seem to figure it out.

**EDIT**: Added an image of what it currently does.
[image]

Comment: Anyone can help me?

Comment: It sounds to me like you are trying to re-invent `GridLayoutGroup`. You do know that already exist in Unity and it works well?

Comment: I saw it passing by, but couldn't get it to work. My objects get instantiated during runtime, and so are their parents. There are 4 parent's above my child objects and they all get instantiated during runtime. I couldn't find a way to get GridLayoutGroup to work. I tried, but no luck

Comment: What? It's so easy to use. Please explain how you tried to use it and I will tell you what you did wrong. What issues where you having and how did you try to use it?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `GridLayoutGroup` along with a prefab that has a `LayoutElement` and the `PageObjectBase` components.

You would have to instantiate the prefab and make it a child of the GameObject which has the `GridLayoutGroup` component.

This way you can set the desired image for every object by accessing the `PageObjectBase` and the `GridLayoutGroup` will take care of the layout of images.